# Use rvmrc or ruby-version file to set a project gemset with RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm, rvmrc

I use RVM, the [Ruby Version Manager](https://rvm.io/) to specify a Ruby version and a set of gems for each of my Rails projects.

I have a `.rvmrc` file to automatically select a Ruby version and gemset whenever I `cd` into a project directory.

After installing RVM 1.19.0, I get a message

> You are using `.rvmrc`, it requires trusting, it is slower and it is
>   not compatible with other ruby managers, you can switch to
>   `.ruby-version` using `rvm rvmrc to [.]ruby-version` or ignore this
>   warnings with `rvm rvmrc warning ignore
>   /Users/userName/code/railsapps/rails-prelaunch-signup/.rvmrc`,
>   `.rvmrc` will continue to be the default project file in RVM 1 and RVM
>   2, to ignore the warning for all files run `rvm rvmrc warning ignore
>   all.rvmrcs`.

Should I continue using my `.rvmrc` file or should I switch to a `.ruby-version` file? Which is optimal? What are the ramifications?

Answer (score 382, accepted):

If your `.rvmrc` file contains custom shell code, continue using `.rvmrc` as it allows you to include any shell code.

If your only aim is to switch Ruby versions, then use `.ruby-version` which is supported by other Ruby version switchers such as [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby). This file also does not require trusting as it is just the name of a Ruby version and will not be executed in any way.

If you use `.ruby-version` you can include `@gemset` in the file but this will not be compatible with other switchers. To maintain compatibility use the gemset name in a separate file `.ruby-gemset` which is ignored by other tools *(it works only together with `.ruby-version`)*.

For example, if you have a simple `.rvmrc`:

```
rvm use 1.9.3@my-app
```

It can be transformed to `.ruby-version`:

```
1.9.3
```

And `.ruby-gemset`:

```
my-app
```

Be sure to remove the `.rvmrc` file as it takes precedence over any other project configuration files:

```
rm .rvmrc
```

Comment: Note that not all applications yet support the newer .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset files but only .rvmrc. (RubyMine in particular). This of course would effect your choice of whether to move to the new system. I had already pointed this out in an answer as it took me alot of time to track this down. However my answer was removed for some reason..

Comment: Is there a link to any "official" documentation on this? I started looking into how this works in the RVM site but just found some vague mention to it as the new rvmrc file but nothing as to how this should work.

Comment: It's not fully documented, but here is what we have already https://rvm.io/workflow/projects/#ruby-versions

Comment: Simply place 1.9.3-p194 into .ruby-version not work for me. Refer to the document above, `rvm --create --ruby-version use 1.9.3-p194` do the work, and the content inside is actually `ruby-1.9.3-p194`

Comment: if it did not worked - open a bug for rvm => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: Previously I had rvm_gemset_create_on_use_flag=1 in my .rcmrc file. How can I get the same functionality by using .ruby-profile and .ruby-gemset ?

Comment: the create on use is enabled by default for .ruby-gemset

Comment: Current versions of RubyMine do support the .ruby-version style. Can confirm with 6.3.2

Answer (score 76):

Quick and easy way to switch from .rvmrc to .ruby-version + .ruby-gemset

```
rvm rvmrc to .ruby-version
```

Comment: True, but it puts [] around the . for some reason that I haven’t figured out. (maybe this is a convention I’m unfamiliar with.) I actually googled the message and found this answer because the awkward phrasing and the [] made me unsure what to actually run.

Comment: @zem The [] in `[.]ruby-version` indicate that [the dot is optional](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1708#issuecomment-22437586); the square brackets are a common convention to indicate optionality (in general, not in ruby.) So you could use a file called "ruby-version", without the dot, and that would also be used. This can be useful if you want more visibility of the file on systems that hide "dot files" by default. I agree it's not that clear, though.

Comment: It says `Could not load .rvmrc`

Answer (score 4):

If you want create the `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` file in a short way you can use the commands like this:

```
rvm use 2.1.1@nancy --create

rvm --create --ruby-version 2.1.1@nancy
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try both.
Go to the root of your project, create a **.rvmrc** file (`touch .rvmrc`), then edit
`rvm use 2.0.0-p451@your_gemset` (your ruby version and gemset name).
After save this file, you can type this command:

`cd ../your_project` (you're in **your_project** directory), and the script in .rvmrc will execute.

The RVM recommend to use ruby-version. You can run this command to switch from .rvmrc to .ruby-version

`rvm rvmrc to .ruby-version`

What it does is create 2 files name **.ruby-version**, and **.ruby-gemset** and add this line

`ruby-2.0.0-p451` in .ruby-version

`your_gemset` in .ruby-gemset

You can try to do it manually if you want :)

Answer (score -1):

Install rvm using:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Install different ruby versions:

```
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm install 1.9.2
```

Switch to specific ruby version. For example, 1.8.7:

```
rvm use 1.8.7
```

To create a gemse:

```
rvm gemset create project_gemset
```

And to use a gemset:

```
rvm gemset use project_gemset
```