# nginx with passenger and rvm 1.19, .rvmrc not work sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am using **nginx**, passenger and **rvm 1.19**

Everything goes fine, but when I created .rvmrc at the root of my rails project, as follow:

> rvm use 1.9.3@rails3213

and start nginx, the first time it works, but after a period of time, the server give me `PAGE NOT FOUND` while I load my page in browser, also when I `cd` to my project it give me this warning:

> You are using '.rvmrc', it requires trusting, it is slower and it is
>   not compatible with       other ruby managers, you can switch to
>   '.ruby-version' using 'rvm rvmrc to [.]ruby-version' or ignore this
>   warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore
>   /home/ubuntu/projects/test/.rvmrc', '.rvmrc' will continue to be the
>   default project file in RVM 1 and RVM 2, to ignore the warning for all
>   files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore all.rvmrcs'.

Using `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392` with `gemset rails3213`

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already trusted your file?

```
 rvm rvmrc trust /home/ubuntu/projects/test
```

BTW, how are you running your app? I mean, you have nginx and what do you use to run rails, and how are you doing the proxy from nginx to rails?

Comment: I have trusted the .rvmrc in my project.

And I use nginx and passenger to run my rails project.

Answer (score 0):

> (...) you can switch to '.ruby-version' using 'rvm rvmrc to
> [.]ruby-version'
>
> or ignore this warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning
> ignore /(...)/.rvmrc' (...)

I would try that.

Also, take a look at [Use rvmrc or ruby-version file to set a project gemset with RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708916/use-rvmrc-or-ruby-version-file-to-set-a-project-gemset-with-rvm)