# RVM version [1.19.1] requires a change to .rvmrc file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

The message :

```
You are using '.rvmrc', it requires trusting, it is slower and it is not compatible with other ruby managers,
you can switch to '.ruby-version' using 'rvm rvmrc to [.]ruby-version'
or ignore this warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/wadawadabingbang/Sites/my_amazing_fn_website/.rvmrc',
'.rvmrc' will continue to be the default project file in RVM 1 and RVM 2,
to ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore all.rvmrcs'.
```

What command, exactly, am I supposed to do?

My ruby version is `ruby-1.9.3-p385`

Comment: Just put your fingers in your ears and run `rvm rvmrc warning ignore all.rvmrcs`

Comment: Never. I would never.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use rvmrc or ruby-version file to set a project gemset with RVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708916/use-rvmrc-or-ruby-version-file-to-set-a-project-gemset-with-rvm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to change your `.rvmrc` file in all your projects you run (as Yule said) `rvm rvmrc warning ignore all.rvmrcs` . It will ignore this warning message for all your projects

If you don't want to change your `.rvmrc` file just for this project, run `rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/wadawadabingbang/Sites/my_amazing_fn_website/.rvmrc`

However this message advices to move your `.rvmrc` to the new system. To do this you just need to create `.ruby-version` with your ruby version inside : `1.9.3-p385` and remove .rvmrc. That's it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you just clarifying for me. So, as RVM is moving from .rvmrc to .ruby-version files and we should all change?

Comment: It is not mandatory to moving from .rvmrc to .ruby-version . It's an advice to uniform ruby version manager because rbenv use .ruby-version. If you don't want to change in all your projects just run `rvm rvmrc warning ignore all.rvmrcs`

Answer (score 2):

I renamed my .rvmrc to .ruby-version and changed the content

from

```
rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag=1
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p0@MYGEMSET --create
```

to

```
ruby-2.0.0-p0@MYGEMSET
```

Comment: +1 for including @GEMSET documentation, which the accepted answer doesn't actually do.

Answer (score 0):

should work after

> `rvm get head`

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [CupraR_On_Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1242752/cuprar-on-rails)'s answer but you don't have to type the name of the directory. I've setup an alias in my `.profile` called `rvm_trust` to run this for me.

```
rvm rvmrc warning ignore `pwd`/.rvmrc
```