# rvm, associate a gemset to a project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

Is it possible to associate a project (that is the root directory of a ruby project) with a certain gemset?
I thought that

> rvm gemset use mytestgemset

would do that, but it is *temporary* and just exiting and entering again restores the original gemset.

I have set up a "test" gemset where i test new version of gems. I don't think i have to issue a `rvm gemset use mytestgemset` each time i launch my test application, do I?

Comment: I think your question is related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708916/use-rvmrc-or-ruby-version-file-to-set-a-project-gemset-with-rvm - maybe these answers could help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the directory of your Rails app add a file called `.rvmrc` with the text `rvm gemset use mytestgemset` in it.

When you cd into that directory rvm will notify you that it has switched the gemset in use. The first time you need to confirm, afterwards it will switch automatically.