# What is the correct way to specify the Ruby version in a Rails app, using RVM, that will be deployed on Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rvm

The [RVM Best Practices](https://rvm.io/rvm/best-practices) state that, to connect a project to a specific Ruby version, you should specify that version in the project-specific `rvmrc` file.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15709012/173634) states that, in most situations, you should use specify the Ruby version in the `.ruby-version` file.

[Heroku says](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) you should specify the Ruby version in `Gemfile`.

What is the correct way to specify a Ruby version, using RVM, if the app will be deployed on Heroku?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.rvmrc` is deprecated and you should use `.ruby-version` instead.

But Heroku does not pay attention to the `.ruby-version`. Heroku wants to have it in the `Gemfile`. So I think you should use both: `.ruby-version` (for you) and `Gemfile` (for Heroku).

Comment: `.rvmrc` is not deprecated - that word is not used in the message, the message is to make you aware, it does not state that `.rvmrc` will no more be used

Answer (score 2):

You need to place it in the Gemfile for Heroku's sake, but if you're using a version manager, then you'll need to use something else for the sake of the version manager. I think the SO answer makes sense in that regard (i.e. the `.ruby-version` file).

Answer (score 1):

Check https://rvm.io/workflow/projects - it says you can use `Gemfile` to specify ruby version for RVM like this:

```
ruby "1.9.3"
```

or something more complicated:

```
ruby File.readlines(".ruby-version").first.strip
```

and then in `.ruby-version`:

```
1.9.3
```

this way it will work also with other ruby environment managers like [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby)