# RVM not recognizing .ruby-version

Tags: ruby, rvm

My application has the following files:

**.ruby-version**

```
ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

**.ruby-gemset**

```
app1
```

When I switch into the application directory the application does not recognize the new version. It switches Ruby versions but the application does not see that until I run `rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247` manually. It works fine with `.rvmrc` but not `.ruby-version`. My RVM is version `1.25.15`.

**Edit**

It's a Rails 4 app and it's using the `bin` directory for executables.

Comment: can you provide the contents of the three files you mention?

Comment: The contents have been included. The `.rvmrc` file had `rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247@app1`.

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk what do you mean by " It switches Ruby versions but the application does not see that" ??

Comment: @bjhaid The ruby version switches (`ruby -v`) but running `bin/rails s`, for example, tells me I need to install missing gems until I switch to the correct Ruby version manually in the terminal.

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk why you running `bin/rails s` and not `rails s`, try the later

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708916/use-rvmrc-or-ruby-version-file-to-set-a-project-gemset-with-rvm

Comment: @bjhaid It's not an issue with running `bin/rails` over `rails`. When switching into the directory it should say `Using /Users/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247 with gemset app1` but it does not tell me anything.

Comment: are you still using the `.rvmrc` in your project along the `.ruby-`s?

Comment: @majioa No, only `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset`.

Comment: try this: `cd your_app`, `ruby -v`, `bundle exec ruby -v`, `bundle exec rails s` or `bundle exec bin/your_bin`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after a fresh install. The problem was , that the rvm source script was not running . It started to work after i run this:

```
source /home/myuser/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

To solve this permanently. Open your terminal and run this:

```
echo "source /home/myuser/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have a `.rvmrc` file in your project root folder.

You might need to update or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by reinstalling RVM and all the ruby gemsets. This does not answer the question as to why it was doing it but just in case someone is stuck with the same issue, here is one solution.

Uninstall RVM

```
rvm implode
```

Install RVM (after rebooting your PC to clean up the junk that was left behind)

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use ruby with gemset version

`rvm use ruby-2.0.0@app1`

and execute bundle after that

`bundle install`

Comment: That works fine. The problem is with RVM not recognizing the `.ruby-version` file or not treating it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
Try this command:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

to reinstall rvm.